$D_{\bf A}{\bf Ax}$
For ${\bf A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, {\bf x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, what is $D_{\bf A}{\bf Ax}$ assuming ${\bf x}$ is fixed and ${\bf A}$ varies? That is, what is the total derivative? I have seen the Kronecker product version of this answer, that is the one with vectorizing ${\bf A}$ as follows
$${\bf Ax} = ({\bf x}^T \otimes I) vec({\bf A}) $$
but to me it must follow
$$\implies D_{ vec({\bf A})}{\bf Ax} = {\bf x}^T \otimes I$$ which isnt even the derivative I want. In short, I want a linear operator $D$ such that near ${\bf A}$, we have that $L: \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \to \mathbb{R}^m : {\bf h} \to{\bf Ax} + D{\bf h}$ is the best linear approximation. By the way, I'm less concerned about the answer to this question as opposed to a matrix proof, one that doesn't use the coefficients and one that actually makes sense.
And herein lies the crux of this question; is this even possible? I mean ${\bf Ax} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $D{\bf h}$ where ${\bf h} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is defined implies $D \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times m} \implies D{\bf h} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n} \not = \mathbb{R}^m \ni {\bf Ax}$  (unless interestingly enough $n$ is a factor of $m$). As a side note I've not worked with tensors, so if this is the place to introduce them feel free to do so.
Wait a second, re-reading this I just realized, is $L \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times (m \times n)}$ (if that's how you write it) a tensor? And is this the space $D$ belongs to, and is $D$ a tensor?

A linear approximation must be with respect to a variable, in this case I want the best linear approximator of ${\bf Ax}$ w.r.t ${\bf A}$

Sorry @EricTowers the original version was very unclear, it's updated now.

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\D{\Delta}
\def\d{\delta}
$In index notation, differentiation is straightforward
$$\eqalign{
y_i &= A_{il}x_l \\
\grad{y_i}{A_{jk}}
 &= \LR{\grad{A_{il}}{A_{jk}}}x_l
 &= \LR{\d_{ij}\d_{kl}}x_l
 &= \d_{ij}x_k
}$$
The quantity on the LHS has three free indices, so it's a third-order tensor.
It can be written in tensor notation using a dyadic product $(\star)$ and the identity matrix $(I)$
$$\eqalign{
\grad{y}{A} = I\star x
}$$
And when used in a linear approximation, you must use the double-dot product
$$\eqalign{
y + \D y &= y + \LR{\grad{y}{A}}:\D A \\
\LR{y + \D y}_i &= y_i + \LR{\grad{y_i}{A_{jk}}}\,\D A_{jk} \\
}$$

This can actually be solved quite easily by using the exact fact that you pointed out: The derivative is the best possible linear approximation near the point we are taking it.
Now we have the function $f: \mathbb R^{m \times n} \to \mathbb R^m$ given by $A \mapsto Ax$. We want to calculate $Df(A) = D_A(Ax)$, the derivative of this function at a point $A$ (in this case a matrix).
Now by Taylor's theorem we have $f(A+H)= f(A) + Df(A)H + \mathcal O(H^2)$, so starting from the left and expanding, the term that is linear in $H$ is exactly $D_A(Ax)$ evaluated in the direction $H$.
Let's plug everything in: $f(A+H)= (A+H)x = Ax + Hx = f(A) + Hx$. This implies
$$D_A(Ax)H = Hx,$$
in other words, the derivative at point $A$ (in $\mathbb R^{m \times n}$) is the linear map that maps a direction $H \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$) to $Hx \in \mathbb R^n$. In particular, the derivative is independent of the point $A$: it is the same at every matrix $A$. This is due to the fact that the expression $Ax$ is linear, both w.r.t to $x$ and w.r.t. $A$.
This is another instance of the rule of thumb "a linear map is its own derivative". To compute the derivative (at any point) we have to multiply the input $H$ by $x$ which is the same as to compute the function:
$$D_A(Ax)H = f(H).$$
Of course, linear algebra tells us that we can find a representation matrix for $D_A(Ax)$ which would be a $(m \times n) \times m$-matrix; but really knowing how this map acts on an element plugged in gives us all the info we need.

Yea I was actually able to get up to here and realized $D$ is a tensor but I couldn't solve for it. What is the actual representation?

I don't understand what you are looking for: The matrix representation is easy but not very insightful (it is just an $m \times mn$-matrix where in each row $i$ you have entries $x_1, \dots, x_n$ starting from the $((i-1)n+1)$-th entry of the row. But the way this tensor works is given by my answer and I believe this "what does the object do" to be more insightful than "give me an actual representation of the object".
